# ssrs table header and report viewer control

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, reportviewer2008

> I have called ssrs report from asp.net using reportviewer. When
>   viewing the report from asp.net the table header is repeated twice and
>   overlaps on reportviewer control(the one with paging and export
>   button) of asp.net. I have tried giving some space, padding and margin
>   but couldn't fix it. The header is fine when viewed from ssrs report
>   manager.I have used 3-4 table in an rdl with each table displayed as
>   page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.Freezing of row headers are not supported in ie 8.Changing the Fixeddata property of the row to false solved the problem